# Wordpress tooltips not visible after ajax req

Tags: ajax, wordpress, tooltip

I have a problem with tooltips after importing ajax in Wordpress.

The plugin is:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/devvn-image-hotspot/

The plugin uses: jQuery PowerTip 
https://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/

Tooltips not visible.

**custom.js**

```
(function($){
    'use strict';
    $(function (e) {
        $('.get_project').on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var postid = $(this).attr('data-postid');
            console.log(postid);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'my_load_ajax_content',
                    postid: postid,
                }
            }).done(function (data) {

                $('.TARGETDIV').html(data).trigger('post-load');



            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**functions.php**

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {
    $pid = intval($_POST['postid']);
    $the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid));

    if ($the_query->have_posts() && $pid > 0) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $data = '
            <div class="post-container">
                <div id="project-content">
                    <h2 class="custom-h2">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>
                    <!-- <div class="entry-content">'. get_the_content() . '</div> -->
                    <div class="entry-content">' . do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $pid)). '</div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            ';
        }
    }
    else {
        $data = '<div id="postdata">'.__('Not found', THEME_NAME).'</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo '<div id="postdata">'. $data .'</div>';
    die();
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );

function my_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script' );


}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

It looks like the data is being returned. Tooltip not visible.

Ex.

```
<div class="box_view_html"><span class="close_ihp"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve"><g><path d="M153.7,153.7C57.9,249.5,10,365.3,10,499c0,135.7,47.9,251.5,143.7,347.3l0,0C249.5,942.1,363.3,990,499,990c135.7,0,251.5-47.9,347.3-143.7C942.1,750.5,990,634.7,990,499c0-135.7-47.9-249.5-143.7-345.3l0,0C750.5,57.9,634.7,10,499,10C365.3,10,249.5,57.9,153.7,153.7z M209.6,211.6l2-2C289.4,129.7,387.2,89.8,499,89.8c113.8,0,209.6,39.9,291.4,121.8c79.8,77.8,119.8,175.6,119.8,287.4c0,113.8-39.9,209.6-119.8,291.4C708.6,870.3,612.8,910.2,499,910.2c-111.8,0-209.6-39.9-287.4-119.8C129.8,708.6,89.8,612.8,89.8,499C89.8,387.2,129.8,289.4,209.6,211.6z"/><path d="M293.4,331.3c0,12,4,22,12,29.9L443.1,497L305.4,632.7c-8,8-12,18-12,29.9c0,10,4,18,12,26c8,8,18,12,28,12c12,0,20-4,27.9-10L499,552.9l135.7,137.7c8,6,16,10,28,10c12,0,21.9-4,27.9-10c8-8,12-18,12-28c0-12-4-21.9-12-29.9L554.9,497l135.7-135.7c8-8,12-18,12-27.9c0-12-4-22-12-29.9c-6-8-16-12-25.9-12c-12,0-21.9,4-29.9,12L499,441.1L363.3,303.4c-8-8-18-12-29.9-12c-10,0-20,4-28,12C297.4,311.4,293.4,321.4,293.4,331.3z"/></g></svg></span><p>Tooltip text</p>
</div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem today and hunted around for a solution. It seems when returning from ajax all the point data is unbound and only gets rebound on the next `$(document).ready()`

You could force a new firing of this by putting this in the success part of the ajax callback:

```
$('body').html($('body').html());
```

As I was viewing the output in a popup this didn't work for me so I had to call the code in `maps.points.js` via a function call.

Put this in the success part of the AJAX call:

```
success: function(response){
  // refresh the popup with response data ...       
  reload_map_data();
}
```

and this is the function call:

```
function reload_map_data(){
            $('.ihotspot_hastooltop').each(function(){
                $(this).data('powertip', function() {
                    var htmlThis = $(this).parents('.ihotspot_tooltop_html').attr('data-html');
                    return htmlThis;
                });
                var thisPlace = $(this).parents('.ihotspot_tooltop_html').data('placement');
                $(this).powerTip({
                    placement: thisPlace,
                    smartPlacement: true,
                    mouseOnToPopup: true,
                }).on({
                    powerTipClose: function() {
                        $('#powerTip').html('');
                    }
                });;
                $('body').on('click','.close_ihp',function () {
                    $.powerTip.hide();
                });
            })
        }
```